# jquery html calender not picking dates from array of not available dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

Still trying to get hold of JQuery. Not really good at it.

I have a problem with html calender. I am able to load it with current month auto selected. On changing drop down selection it does switch to that month but doesn't pick the dates "Not Available" to book.

Here is the code:

```
        var cal = new Calendar();

        var unavailable_days_month_1 = [1,2,3];
        var unavailable_days_month_2 = [4,5,6];
        var unavailable_days_month_3 = [7,8,9];
        var unavailable_days_month_4 = [10,11,12];
        var unavailable_days_month_5 = [13,14,15];
        var unavailable_days_month_6 = [16,17,18];
        var unavailable_days_month_7 = [19,20,21];
        var unavailable_days_month_8 = [22,23,24];
        var unavailable_days_month_9 = [25,26,27];
        var unavailable_days_month_10 = [28,29,30];
        var unavailable_days_month_11 = [2,4,31];
        var unavailable_days_month_12 = [7,9,11];

        var current_date = new Date();
        var current_month = (current_date.getMonth() + 1);
        var current_year_month = (1900 + current_date.getYear()) + "-" + current_month;
        tjq("#select-month").find("[value='" + current_year_month + "']").prop("selected", "selected");
        cal.generateHTML(current_date.getMonth(), (1900 + current_date.getYear()), "unavailable_days_month_" + current_month);
        tjq(".calendar").html(cal.getHTML());

        tjq("#select-month").change(function() {
            var selected_year_month = tjq("#select-month option:selected").val();
            var year = parseInt(selected_year_month.split("-")[0], 10);
            var month = parseInt(selected_year_month.split("-")[1], 10);
/* My problem starts from here */
            cal.generateHTML(month - 1, year, "unavailable_days_month_" + month);
            tjq(".calendar").html(cal.getHTML());
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're returning a string, instead of the array. Reference:

```
"unavailable_days_month_" + month
```

So I'd make a function, if I were you, if you want to do something that should work most of the times, if users don't exploit it.

```
function getUnavailDays (month) {
   if (month === 1) return unavailable_days_month_1
   if (month === 2) return unavailable_days_month_2
   if (month === 3) return unavailable_days_month_3
   // and so on...
   return // return if none of the cases match above.
}
```

It might not be the best solution, but it's **something** atleast.

You can call it using `getUnavailDays(month)` later on.

EDIT:

Better solution;

```
function getUnavailDays (month) {
   switch (month) {
      case 1:
        return unavailable_days_month_1
      case 2:
        return unavailable_days_month_2
      // and so on..
      default:
        return
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Cernodile.. Could you suggest where I can put this script?.. Can't really figure out.

Comment: Below the arrays, would be ideal.

Comment: Alternatively you could use jagged arrays, like `unavailable_days_month = [[1, [1, 2, 3]], [2, [4,5,6]]]`, and parse through them in a for loop or something.